# ExtJS 4 - Display Grid using remote json store

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs4.2

I am a newbie with ExtJS 4. I am trying to display a result list which fetches results from a remote store, without much success.

Below is the view file

```
Ext.define('Crm.view.CompanyList', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.companyList',
    store : 'Crm.store.Companies',
    title : 'Company List',

    initComponent: function(){
        this.columns = [ {
            text : 'ID',
            width : 150,
            dataIndex : 'id'
        }, {
            text : 'LastName',
            width : 150,
            sortable : false,
            hideable : false,
            dataIndex : 'lastName'
        }, {
            text : 'First Name',
            width : 150,
            sortable : false,
            hideable : false,
            dataIndex : 'firstName'
        }, {
            text : 'Street',
            flex : 1,
            sortable : false,
            hideable : false,
            dataIndex : 'street'
        } ];
        this.dockedItems = [ {
            xtype : 'pagingtoolbar',
            store : 'Companies',
            dock : 'bottom',
            displayInfo : true
        } ];
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

and below is the Model

```
Ext.define('Crm.model.Company',{
    extend  : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields  : [
        {name:'id',type:'string'},
        {name:'lastName',type:'string'},
        {name:'firstName',type:'string'},
        {name:'street',type:'string'}
    ]
});
```

This is how the store is defined

```
Ext.define('Crm.store.Companies', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: 'Crm.model.Company',
    model: 'Crm.model.Company',
    autoLoad: {start: 0, limit: 5},
    pageSize: 5,
    remoteSort: true,
    sorters: [{
        property : 'lastName',
        direction: 'asc'
    }],
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url : 'http://extjsinaction.com/crud.php?model=Employee&method=READ',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            idProperty      : 'id',
            //  successProperty : 'meta.success',
            totalProperty   : 'meta.total'
        }
    }
});
```

and finally the HTML file which is expected the render the Grid in browser

```
    &lt;html&gt;
    &lt;head&gt;
    &lt;link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.2.0-gpl/resources/css/ext-all.css"&gt;
    &lt;script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.2.0-gpl/ext-all-dev.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
    &lt;script type="text/javascript" src="Crm/view/CompanyList.js"  &gt;&lt;/script&gt;
    &lt;script type="text/javascript" src="Crm/model/Company.js"  &gt;&lt;/script&gt;
    &lt;script type="text/javascript" src="Crm/store/Companies.js"  &gt;&lt;/script&gt;
    &lt;/head&gt;
    &lt;body&gt;
    &lt;script type="text/javascript" &gt;
    Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Crm.view.CompanyList', {
    });
    );
    &lt;/script&gt;
    &lt;/body&gt;
    &lt;/html&gt;
```

When I run this in browser, I get the below error in browser console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffered' of undefined ext-all-dev.js:145555
```

Can someone please guide me to resolve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason your code fails is that the grid does not have a store. You configure store as string (class name) but this approach works only if you use MVC with Ext.Application when Ext creates the store for you.

You can make the above working by creating the store in `initComponent` of the grid:

```
this.store = Ext.create('Crm.store.Companies', {});
```

For long run I recommend to use `Sencha Cmd` and MVC (MVVM for Ext 5) architecture.